# Having trouble positioning a Canvas HTML5 game on my webpage

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have created a game and saved it in a seperate .js file and imported it into my html page by placing the following code in the middle of my body code of a html file:

```
<div class="gameElement">
     <script src="scripts/game.js"></script>
</div>
```

After trying different ways of importing my game the same thing happens so I'm pretty sure it isn't to do with the method I have imported my game with.

The problem I have is that whenever I want to add some css to the "gameElement" to position it very little happens; it just seems to be positioned after the div that I have placed it in (rather than being placed in the middle of my div. I have tried rearranging my code and placing it in different div's but nothing seems to work well.

My primary objective is to place this "gameElement" in a div and place it in the middle of my page rather than it being placed after everything on my page.

Does anyone know why the positioning of HTML5 games is so difficult?

P.S. Apologies for the poor description.

Comment: What is your question? It cannot be "Does anyone know why the positioning of HTML5 games is so difficult?" If you need help try posting snippets of the CSS or whatever else you think my help other people guide you.

Comment: It doesn't matter what CSS I try very little happens.
The problem is that when I place the game I have imported into a div with an id the game ends up being placed after where the div is positioned on screen and not inside the "block" that I have created for it to be placed into.

Comment: Then show that. What kind of answers are you seeking?

Answer (score 0):

Placing a javascript file anywhere on the page doesn't define where its output will be, but rather when it will run.

You have to define the position of the file's output inside the file itself.

You can put the game file anywhere you want.

Comment: After editing my game's code I do notice that the game is then repositioned... however it still places itself after the div that I have positioned it in.